# GIT: How do I rebase nested branches?

Tags: git, merge

My structure looks like this->

```
master
  develop 
    project
      <sprint_number>
        <task_number>
```

I work on the task_number branch. Then I merge task with the sprint branch. Then I merge sprint with the project branch. In this way, all of the commits on project are sprints, and all of the commits on sprint are tasks. After merging into project branch, I submit a merge request and a code review is performed before merging into develop.

Should I do a rebase all the way down the chain? For example:

```
git checkout develop
git rebase master
git checkout project
git rebase develop
git checkout <sprint_number>
git rebase project
git checkout <task_number>
git rebase <sprint_number>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Git branch names don't actually nest in any sense: they're just pointers to specific commits.

#### First, draw (part of) the commit DAG

What we need to do here, as usual, is draw some commit **D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raph (DAG) fragments and consider cases where rebasing makes sense.  So we start with your example:

> ```
> master
>   develop 
>     project
>       <sprint_number>
>         <task_number>
> ```

and add some nodes (and give them single-uppercase-letters instead of their "true name" hashes like `a1cf93a...` since those are too big and unwieldy):

```
A <- B <- C                <-- master
      \
       D <- E              <-- develop
             \
              F <- G       <-- project
                    \
                     H     <-- <sprint_number>
                      \
                       I   <-- <task_number>
```

(the backslashes here should be up-and-left arrows but those are too hard to draw in plain text).

That is, in this case we have (at least) three commits on `master` (there may be any number of commits before commit `A` that we simply did not draw in).  The tip of `master` is commit `C`, which points back to commit `B`, which points back to `A`.

We have two commits on `develop` that are not also on `master`: commit `E` is the tip of `develop` and `E` points back to `D`, while `D` points back to `B`.  Commit `B`, along with all of its ancestors (`A` and anything earlier), is on *both* `master` *and* `develop`.

Meanwhile commit `G` is the tip of `project`; `G` points back to `F` which points back to `E`, and so on.  This means commits `A` and `B` are, in fact, on all *three* branches.  But wait, there's more!  `H` is the tip of `<sprint_number>` and `H` points back to `G`, and so on; and `I` is the tip of `<task_number>` and `I` points back to `H`.

In the end, this means that commits `A` and `B` are on (at least) five branches (the five shown here), and `D` and `E are on at least four branches, and so on.

#### Decide if rebasing is needed and allowed

In git, *rebasing* actually means *copying commits to new, slightly different/modified commits*.  (This may not be the right approach.  We'll get to that later, though, because it won't make sense until you know more.)

The tip of `master` is now commit `C` rather than commit `B`.  Presumably, earlier, the tip of master was `B`, and that was when we made commit `D` (and maybe `E` as well).  But now you're considering rebasing `develop` onto the new tip of `master`.

To achieve this you must *copy* commits `D` and `E` to new, different commits.  We'll call these copies `D'` and `E'`.  Even if nothing else changes—and it's likely that something else does change, specifically whatever is different between `B` and `C` will go into the new `D'`—the copy `D'` of original commit `D` has to point to commit `C` rather than to commit `B`.

Drawing *just* this copy phase (leaving out everything hung off the original `E`) we get:

```
A - B - C             <-- master
     \    \
      \     D' - E'   <-- develop (after rebase)
       \
        D - E         [abandoned]
```

(I've simplified the left pointing arrows this time too, now that we know that commits point leftward.)  But while the original `D` and `E` are no longer pointed-to by branch name `develop`, they're still *reachable* once we fill in the rest of the drawing:

```
A - B - C             <-- master
     \    \
      \     D' - E'   <-- develop (after rebase)
       \
        D-E
           \
            F-G       <-- project
               \
                H     <-- <sprint_number>
                 \
                  I   <-- <task_number>
```

What's particularly significant at this point is that original commits `D` and `E` are *no longer on `develop`.

#### How rebase works

Ignoring `--fork-point` (which can be a solution here), the `git rebase` command really takes three arguments, one of which is normally just taken from `HEAD`:

- the tip-most commit to copy (this is normally just "your current branch", i.e., `HEAD`);
- a specifier that *limits* which commits to copy, i.e., specifies—but indirectly—commits *not* to copy; and
- the identity of the commit to which the first copied commit will be added.

The latter two are usually combined into one `<upstream>` argument.  Meanwhile you first do a `git checkout` of the branch to rebase, to set the first argument.  For instance, if we were to decide to rebase `develop` onto `master`:

```
git checkout develop
git rebase master
```

Here the tip-most commit to copy is the `HEAD` commit as usual, which because of the `git checkout` is the tip-most commit of `develop`, and the starting place at which the new copies will be grown is the tip of `master`.  Git starts by considering coping *every* commit that is on `develop` (which would be `A`, `B`, `D`, and `E`), but it's told here to *avoid* copying every commit that is on `master`, which means `A`, `B`, and `C`.

*(Wait, what?  We're not supposed to copy `C`?  But we weren't going to copy `C` in the first place!  Well, no problem then, we just won't copy it!)*  That's how we can combine the two things into one `<upstream>` argument.  We want to add the new copies after `C`, and at the same time, avoid copying `C` and everything in the path leading back from `C`.

So if we choose to go ahead and do this `git rebase`, we'll copy `D` and `E` to `D'` and `E'` and end up with the new graph fragment we drew.

That's great for `develop`, but what happens now if we do:

```
git checkout project
git rebase develop
```

This time, we'll ask git to copy everything reachable from the tip of `project`—these are `G`, `F`, `E`, `D`, `B`, and `A` (and maybe something more)—to the tip of the already-rebased `develop`, i.e., commit `E'`.

This is a problem.  It may be a self-solving one, if we're lucky, because rebase will detect *some* cases of copied commits and avoid re-copying them.  That is, when git goes to copy `D` to a(nother) new copy `D''`, it *may* detect that `D` is already present in `E'`.  If it *does* detect this it will just skip the copy.  The same happens when it goes to copy `E` to `E''`: it *may* detect that this is not needed, and skip the copy.

On the other hand, git's detector may be fooled, and it might copy `D` and/or `E`.  We definitely don't want that, so it's best to avoid asking git to copy them at all.

There are a number of ways to ask, including an interactive rebase (where we get to edit the `pick` instructions, so we can delete the two `pick` lines for commits `D` and `E`), or being more clever with arguments to `git rebase`:

```
git checkout project
git rebase --onto develop 'project@{1}'
```

This second command uses the reflog history to tell git that the commits to copy are those that are on `project` (the current branch) that are not contained within the *previous* tip of `project`.  That is, `'project@{1}'` resolves to the commit ID of original (un-copied) commit `E`.  This will therefore copy just commits `F` and `G`, to `F'` and `G'`.

(Incidentally, if you draw your DAGs on a whiteboard with colored markers, you can use colors to represent the original commits and their copies.  I find this easier to read than all the `D'` and `D''` notation.  I just can't draw it on StackOverflow.)

We can repeat this process with the sprint and task, using the reflog to identify commits to leave out.

Since git 1.9, `git rebase` now has `--fork-point`, which essentially automates what we're doing here with the reflogs.  (There was a bug fix in git 2.1 for `git rebase --fork-point` failing to discover commits that don't need to be copied, so it would be wise to limit using this option to 2.1-or-later.)  That could therefore be a way to do this.

Finally, before returning to the question of whether this is a good idea at all, I'll make one more note.  Instead of rebasing `develop` on `master`, and `project` on `develop`, and so on, suppose we *started* by rebasing the task.  This would tell git to copy commit `D` to `D'`, `E` to `E'`, `F` to `F'`, and so on all the way down to copying `I` to `I'`.  The task branch would then point to new commit `I'`, whose history chain reaches back to `C`.  Now all we need to do here is re-point the sprint branch, the `project` branch, and the `develop` branch at the copied commits, by finding the right copy.  The updated `develop` should point to `E'`; the updated `project` should point to `G'`; and the updated sprint branch should point to `H'`.

If there are additional sprint and/or task branches, they probably need to have some commit(s) copied that would not be copied by the above, though, so this trick has to be used carefully.  As always, it will help to draw the DAG first.

#### Is rebasing right?

If you have a branch structure this complex, rebasing may be the wrong approach.  Even if not, it may still be the wrong way to do this.

Remember that, as we just saw, rebasing involves *copying* commits, and then moving branch labels to point to the new copies, instead of the originals.  When you do this with a repository that only *you* use, it's usually not too terribly confusing, because you move all your branch labels and you are now done: you either have the old, pre-copy state, or the new, post-copy state, and you can ignore all the intermediate (mid-rebase) state except for the brief period of doing all these rebases.

If *someone else* is sharing this repository, though, consider what you will do *to them*.  Before you did all this massive rebasing, they had what they *thought* were the right `develop`, `project`, sprint, and task branch pointers.  They were using the original (not yet copied) commits and making their own new commits that depend on those original commits.

Now you come along and tell them: "Oh, hey, forget all those old commits!  Use these brand-new shiny ones instead!"  Now they have to go find everything *they* did that depended on the *old* commits, and update all of those to depend instead on the new ones.

In other words, they must deal with an "upstream rebase"—or in fact, from numerous upstream rebases.  It's generally not a lot of fun (though the same `--fork-point` code that makes it possible for you to automate this, also makes it possible for them to automate their recovery from the upstream rebases).

There is a time limit on `--fork-point`, because it uses reflog entries, and reflog entries expire.  If you have not reconfigured things, git defaults to expiring the critical reflog entries after 30 days, so *if* you do this, everyone else has about a month to recover from it.

Comment: Great answer. Would be nice, though, to have explicit examples of how to use `--fork-point`.

Comment: @ijoseph: I'm not a big fan of `--fork-point`. Used carelessly, if I remember right, you can lose your own commits: I remember wondering about this and creating a test case and being annoyed by the result. So I'd recommend using `git rebase -i` without `--fork-point` and working from there.

Answer (score 0):

> In this way, all of the commits on project are sprints, and all of the commits on sprint are task

You don't need to do it this way. simply use the pull request you have created since all the code will be merged into develop at the end.

As soon as you open the pull request you can also delete your local branches and keep only the latest one for future changes if you will need any.

Comment: I don't understand, I pull all the way down? I want the actually work branch to contain the latest version of master.

Comment: If you branches out from master and you want to get all the latest changes from master again simply pull the changes.Its not what you described in your question

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a nested branch in git. If you have a branch named foo, and another branch named foo/bar, they are just two different branches. Theres no relationship between these branches - treat them the way you would treat any two separate branches.

Comment: They are nested in terms of their commit structure. I don't want develop to have every commit on my working branch.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "nested in terms of their commit structure". Do you mean that you made a branch, did some work, commited, and then made a new branch based off that, did some work on it and commited?

Comment: I want all the commits in the develop branch to be releases, all of the commits in the project branch to be sprints, all of the commits in each sprint branch to be tasks associated with that sprint. Each task branch will have  multiple daily commits to save code.