# git rebase all intermediate branches

Tags: git, rebase

Suppose I have a set of BRANCHES (not commits) A, B, C and D like the following

```
A
|
B   C
|   |
 \ /
  D
```

I would like to rebase branch `A` over branch `C`.

Doing a normal rebase would keep branch `B` in the same place. Like this:

```
    A
    |
B   C
|   |
 \ /
  D
```

But I'd like to also move branch `B` keeping its relative position to branch `A` in the rebase.

The end (desired) result would be the following:

```
A
|
B
|
C
|
D
```

at the moment I'm doing this manually, rebasing branch `A` over branch `C` and then moving branch `B`. Is there an option for the `git rebase` command which allows me to do this with one command?

Using a simple `git rebase C` while being in `A` (or a `git rebase C A`) is not enough because it moves only the `A` branch, while the `B` branch remains where it is (its commits are copied, but the branch is not moved)

Comment: There isn't a convenient Git command to do this, and in the fully general case it can be difficult. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/61216739/1256452 for instance.

Comment: @torek it theory it doesn't sound that difficult to me. It would work rebasing branch `A` over branch `C` and moving all the branches attached to the copied commits to their new copies.

Comment: Yes, and years ago, I wrote a script that did that - but along the way I discovered where you run into various problems, such as when there are branch-and-merge operations within the section you want to rebase, or multiple independent branch tips with common intermediate commits. Git now has `--rebase-merges`, which has most of the machinery one would need, but it's still not quite all there.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Branches are just labels on commits.  it is entirely unclear what the heck you are trying to accomplish, and why from branch b `git rebase c --update-refs --preserve-merges` isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Git v2.38 (released Oct 3 2022) added a new feature [`--update-refs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---update-refs) that does exactly what you are asking for. So in your case:

```
git rebase --update-refs C A
```

The option can also be enabled by default:

```
git config --global rebase.updateRefs true
```

Answer (score 1):

In branch B, run this

```
git rebase C A
```

Comment: Rebases the commits while leaving branch B intact. Interesting.

Comment: this moves `A` over `C`, while I want to move `A` and `B` over `C`

Comment: @marcosh it moves both. Make a copy of the repository and test it

Comment: @marcosh maybe you are skipping B as rebase is replaying the commits onto the new branch, e.g. `git rebase --skip`?

Comment: it moves the commits, but I want to move also the branch `B`

Comment: @marcosh My solution moves the branch. However if you can't go back, you can just delete the branch and create a new one with the same name where you want it.

Comment: I edited the question, making more explicit that A, B, C and D are branches

Comment: That really doesnt change anything @marcosh

Answer (score 0):

If I render your four commits in the style I prefer for StackOverflow postings, it looks like this, with newer commits towards the right:

```
  C   <-- branch1
 /
D
 \
  B--A   <-- branch2
```

The two names—you have not told us what they are, so I just used `branch1` and `branch2` here—contain the raw hash ID of actual commits `C` and `A`, which are the tip commits of the two branches.  (`C` and `A` stand in for real hash IDs, which are big and ugly and random-looking.)

The parent of commit `A` is commit `B`.  The parent of commit `B` is commit `D`.  The parent of commit `C` is commit `D` as well.  (If there are commits before commit `D`, we cannot see them.)

You say that you would like to have:

```
D--C--B--A
```

as your final result.  You cannot: commit `B`'s parent is commit `D`, now and forever.  You *can* have:

```
D--C--B'-A'
```

where `B'` is a *copy* of `B` but with a different hash ID because it also has a different parent (and probably a different snapshot as well).  Similarly, `A'` must be the result of taking commits `B'` and `A` out and recommitting something slightly different: the parent if `A'` is `B'`, and `A'` probably holds a different snapshot than `A`, just like `B'` probably holds a different snapshot than `B`.

Commits `B` and `A` will continue to exist, i.e., your repository will have:

```
D--C--B'-A'
    \
     B--A
```

in it.  If you write down the actual hash IDs of `B` and `A` somewhere, and type them back in later, you will see that the commits continue to exist.  (They will stick around for at least 30 days by default, in case you decide you want them back.)

What's missing from your final-result, however, is which *names* you want to have pointing to *which commits*.  You can, if you like, have both names point to commit `A'`, like this:

```
D--C--B'-A'  <-- branch1, branch2
```

or you can have `branch2` point to `A'` and leave `branch1` pointing to existing commit `C`, like this:

```
     B'-A'  <-- branch2
    /
D--C   <-- branch1
```

The set of Git commands that you can to use to achieve the final result depends on which of these final results you want.

Note that [Saurabh P Bhandari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61325438/1256452) is equivalent to:

```
git checkout --detach branch2     # or git checkout <hash-of-A>
git rebase branch1
```

which produces:

```
     B'-A'  <-- HEAD
    /
D--C   <-- branch1
    \
     B--A   <-- branch1
```

i.e., you are *detached HEAD* mode in the end, with *neither* branch name moved.

Since there are two *branch names* involved—`branch1` and `branch2` are the two *names*—it takes, at a minimum, two Git commands to achieve:

```
D--C--B'-A'  <-- branch1, branch2
    \
     B--A   [abandoned]
```

as your final result, if that's what you want.  A minimal set of commands—there are many command sequences that will achieve this result—is:

```
git checkout branch2
git rebase branch1
git push . branch2:branch1
```

which leaves you with your `HEAD` attached to the name `branch2`:

```
D--C--B'-A'  <-- branch1, branch2 (HEAD)
    \
     B--A   [abandoned]
```

[symlink's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61325465/1256452), with name substitutions, amounts to:

```
git checkout branch2
git rebase branch1
git checkout branch1
git merge --ff-only branch2    # the --ff-only is not required here
```

which does the same thing but leaves `HEAD` attached to the name `branch1`:

```
D--C--B'-A'  <-- branch1 (HEAD), branch2
    \
     B--A   [abandoned]
```

The `--ff-only` flag ensures that if something went wrong and the commit identified by the name `branch2` is not now strictly ahead of that identified by `branch1`, Git will produce an error message, rather than a new merge commit.

The `git push . src:dst` command is particularly tricky / sneaky and I don't really recommend it in general, but it illustrates a way to ask Git to fast-forward one of your names—*`dst`*—to point to any given commit, in this case *`src`*.  Here we fast-forward the name `branch1` to make it point to the same commit as `branch2`.  Again, the push command has the *source* on the left and the *destination* on the right, which is why we write this as `branch2:branch1`.

#### The key to understanding all this

Git is all about *commits*.  Each commit has a unique hash ID, and once a commit is made, *no part of it can ever be changed*.  So if you want *different* commits you have to make new ones.  That's usually not a big deal.  That's what `git rebase` *does:* it copies some existing commits to some new-and-improved ones.

You—and Git for that matter—*find* commits, however, by starting with the *last* one in a chain, as identified by a branch name, then working backwards.  (That's why commit `A` is the last one, instead of the first one, in each of our drawings: you put the last one at the top, and I put the last one at the right.)

Having copied a series of commits as found by a particular name, `git rebase` now *drags the name over to point to the last of the new commits*.  For a single name, this is just what you want.

But, after you have copied some series of commits, if there is *more than one name* that you would like moved, *you* must move the remaining names.  That's really all there is to it.

Comment: A, B, C and D are branches, not commits

Comment: @marcosh: aha, that's key information that was missing from your original post. As you can see, all our answers assumed that they were individual commits. Meanwhile, see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/36292272/1256452

Comment: actually the question starts with `Suppose I have a set a branches`, but I'll clarify now

Comment: It does—but that looks like a set of two branches whose names are not supplied...

Comment: I edited the question, making more explicit that A, B, C and D are branches

Comment: The question is about branches not commits

Answer (score -1):

If A is the tip of branch `feature` and C is the tip of branch `master`:

```
A //feature
|
B   C //master
|   |
 \ /
  D
```

```
git checkout feature //if not on feature

git rebase master //rebase feature onto master
```

You can also do this on either branch and get the same result:

```
git rebase master feature //rebase feature onto master
```

The result:

```
A //feature
|
B
| 
C //master
|
D
```

To fast-forward master to point to A:

```
git checkout master //if not on master

git merge feature //merge master with feature
```

Result:

```
A //feature, master
|
B
| 
C 
|
D
```

Comment: if I try this, `B` remains where it is, it does not move over `C`

Comment: @marcosh This moves both A and B over C. You may want to use Saurabh's answer anyway, though, because my solution rewrites the history, while his simply copies A and B over C, leaving the other branch intact.

Comment: I tried it locally, the branch `B` remains where it is and its commits are copied. I want to move also the branch

Comment: I edited the question, making more explicit that A, B, C and D are branches

Comment: The question is about branches not commits